# Считывание нажатий клавиш терминала Python

Tags: python, события, клавиатура

Делаю программу которой требуется считывать нажатия любых клавиш только в терминале Windows(7 - 10), чтобы код по типу такого:

```
import keyboard

def print_pressed_keys(e):
    print(e, e.event_type, e.name)

keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
```

Мог работать, считывать, записывать и т.д. нажатия клавиш **только** внутри программы в терминале Windows и нигде более. Например, если я работаю в блокноте, и при этом включен подобный код, не считывал те клавиши, которые были нажаты внутри блокнота.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте через msvcrt:

```py
import msvcrt
key = ord(msvcrt.getch()) # ord порядковый номер в юникоде
if key == 27:
    print("press ESC")
elif key == 32:
    print("press Spase")
```

При необходимости обернуть в цикл и/или поток.

Comment: Спасибо! Я не знаю как выразить тебе всю благодарность! Крайне благодарен!